# How can i send email with Voting buttons via shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sendmail

I have an existing email chaser system based on linux where we send emails to a large list of individual asking to reply on email with their confirmation and they can reply with options like a1,a2,a3,a4 or a5 which is working ok but teh percentage of response we are receiving is less so to make it more easy for them we would like to add clickable features like Voting buttons, can someone help me in this please?

I know how to do it in vbscript but not sure if linux can do it and I cant find any solution in forums yet, we have limitations which prevent us using any third party tools so we have to use Linux inbuild modules.

If voting is not possible then at-least can generate some clickable links when they click it will generate a corresponding response in subject line which we can grab late by some other process.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `If voting is not possible then at-least can generate some clickable links` :) surely this is half of the question. The clickable link no different to a poll which would also be a link would then need to point to a running web server that would understand that vote a1 a4 and so on - so in essence you may as well build it around a web solution that both sends the email and accepts the answers back - https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Poll this is just an example and no one really uses perl for web development these days -

Comment: I would really recommend rethinking this logic based on shell scripts or something as primitive as this since assuming 2000 people vote a1 how will you know which user it was that clicked a1 and which a2 - as part of the voting url should have a correlation to end user who it was generated for to give a clue as to which users participated which users didn't respond etc etc -

Answer (score 0):

not sure about voting, but you could simply send html email with clickable links etc as below:

```
cat <<EOF | sendmail -t
To: someone@mail.com
Subject: A subject
From: A sender
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
<html>
<body>
<a href="www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't you forget a blank line between after the header part?

Comment: Thanks you all for your response.after some digging I am able to find a workaround for my primary issue which is sending email from Linux with clickable links which can not converted as replies. so I am using below code on my emails and when user click the link it generate a response code in subject line,
mailto:recipient@domain.com?subject=Email%20Subject&body=Body%20Text. 
this is not complete solution asI don't have any system to grab these response from exchange but we have people to extract all response in excel (emaiid and response code) and send it for next step.